# How to check if a pandas column has anything other than specified values?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas dataframe, with column `A`, and we want all the values in that column to be of type category with either `L` or `R` as the value.

How can I raise an exception if we detect that this column has any value other than `L` or `R`? That includes if it was `None`/`null`/`NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can filter on `L` and `R` and then we get the opposite of that filter using the `~` operator like so:

```py
df[~(df['A'].isin(['L', 'R']))]
```

To get a boolean value indicating that additional values are present in the Series, we can write:

```py
len(df[~(df['A'].isin(['L', 'R']))]) == 0
```

We can be being even shorter and quicker by using the [`pandas.Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) method which also returns a boolean value:

```py
~(df['A'].isin(['L', 'R'])).any()
```

Comment: hmm this returns all the rows though, how can we return true or false if L or R is included or if there is something else included? We want to return false if anything other than L or R is in this column

Answer (score 1):

this should work.

```
all(df["A"].isin(["L", "R"]))
```

You could use this in a statement like so

```
if all(df["A"].isin(["L", "R"])):
    print("it works!")
```

If you want to raise an exception if the statement returns false, you could write

```
if not all(df["A"].isin(["L", "R"])):
        raise ValueError("there's a wrong value in col A!")
```

or using assert, simply

```
assert all(df["A"].isin(["L", "R"])), "there's a wrong value in col A!
```

Speed test:

```
%timeit all(df["A"].isin(["L", "R"]))
%timeit len(df[~(df['A'].isin(['L', 'R']))]) == 0
%timeit ~(df['A'].isin(['L', 'R'])).any()

# 55.9 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 167 µs ± 651 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 73.8 µs ± 178 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: @academy- try the benchmarks now the the accepted answer is updated.

Comment: @user17242583 i have included the updated accepted answer in the speed test now.